# what is difference between my code and tutorial code?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.2.3 but Tutorial's teacher using PHP 5.3 I'm writing same code but I can see only error.

Paths:

```
Main
---index.php
---com
   ---User.php
```

---

```
<?php

define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath('../'));
$paths = array(
            APPLICATION_PATH,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/com',
            get_include_path()
);
print_r($paths);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));

require_once('User.php');

$user = new User();
$user->getName();
```

Errors:

```
Warning: require_once(User.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\advanced\index.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'User.php' (include_path='C:\AppServ\www;C:\AppServ\www/com;.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\AppServ\www\advanced\index.php on line 11
```

**Why my code is not running?**

[image]

Maybe you need(User.php):

```
<?php 
Class User
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return "Ricardo Quaresma";
    }
}
?>
```

**SOLVE: http://ideone.com/n77hE**

Comment: Your 2nd `$paths` entry has a forward slash.  Should it be a backslash instead?

Comment: it aren't change anything.. @SenorAmor

Comment: Ok.  Where is 'User.php' located on your computer?  That's where the problem lies.  It's not in any of the folders that PHP is looking inside.

Comment: Try changing your require line to include the full path (`require_once('C:\AppServ\www\com\User.php');`)

Comment: @SenorAmor why i need? Code of tutorial is running why my code is not running? I know using require :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your require statment should be like so:

```
require_once('com/User.php');
```

By the way:
Could you show me the files in a tree view?

Comment: I solve my problem. And I know using require_once function. I'm trying set_path_include_path().

Answer (score -1):

Solve(change as below):

```
<?php
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(''));
$paths = array(
            APPLICATION_PATH,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '\com',
            get_include_path()
);
print_r($paths);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));

require_once('User.php');

$user = new User();
echo $user->getName();
```